# git: automatically add any files updated within a directory to the staging area

Tags: git

I'd like to automatically have files that I save within a directory be added to my project's staging area, i.e. for each file `X`, `git add X` should be run.

Can someone show me the easiest way to do this?

Comment: This is not something git offers out-of-the-box, you will need to implement a solution on your own by using some folder monitoring and script execution which would obviously depend on your OS.

Comment: I don't know how to do this strictly from the command line, though I seem to recall that this is the default behavior for some of the IDE Git plugins, e.g. eGit, which automatically stages anything you modify and save.

Comment: Also doable in `Emacs`

Comment: And on `Linux` you can use a generic `inotify` mechanism to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are at the top of your working directory, you can add all files to staging area using "git add . " command.

## git add .

And if file is tracked you can add all files to staging area using "git commit -a".

## git commit -a -m "-m option can write commit message"